# Autenticação de cadastro de usuário por e-mail em Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou desenvolvendo uma tela de cadastro de usuário, e surgiu a necessidade de autenticar o cadastro do usuário por e-mail, o procedimento seria algo como, ao confirmar o cadastro um e-mail é disparado para o usuário, e o mesmo para concluir o procedimento teria que acessar o seu e-mail e clicar na url de confirmação. Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como fazer, ou que saiba de algum exemplo para indicar? Grato.

Comment: Os colegas Natan e Felipe Borges já me auxiliarão, Grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua dúvida é meio vaga em relação ao ponto onde você esta.

1. O cadastro no banco de dados foi realizado?
2. Consegue enviar e-mail?

Estou partindo do pressuposto que você tem um cadastro realizado no banco de dados e que consegue enviar e-mails. Faça o seguinte:

1. Na tabela do usuário cadastrado, crie um campo de nome "verificado" do tipo int e atribua 0 para não verificado e 1 para verificado. Por padrão todos os cadastros terão o valor 0
2. adicione na tabela de cadastro um campo chamado "token" do tipo varchar
3. cada novo cadastro que for realizado, gere um token único do tipo UUID
4. Envie um link de ativação de cadastro por e-mail para seu usuário. Exemplo de link de ativação: http://www.seusite.com/ativacao?token=TOKEN_EXCLUSIVO_DO_USUARIO
5. O endereço acima irá ler a `query string` `token` e irá verificar se há algum registro que corresponda ao token. Se houver, altere o campo "verificado" para 1

Imagino que você tem uma tela de login. Nessa tela de login você recebe as credenciais do usuário (login e senha). Você deve conceder acesso somente para os usuários que tenham o campo "verificado" igual a 1.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: O cadastro de usuários já foi realizado, e vou implementar a parte de envio de e-mails. A sua sugestão já me ajuda em muito! Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que ajudou. Se essa for a solução, marque minha resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada nesses links, que contém um passo a passo de como fazer.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-verification

https://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/node-email-verification-script/

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!